# Multiple exception status codes with status text as "ok"

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core

I'm working on an exception handler in a small project, no matter what is the exception or the exception code the HTTP response always returns a status text of "ok"

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NizHj.png)

.net core 5 Controller class :

```
using API.Data;
using API.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    public class BuggyController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public BuggyController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("auth")]
        public ActionResult<string> GetSecret()
        {
            return "secret test";
        }

        [HttpGet("not-found")]
        public ActionResult<AppUser> GetNotFound()
        {
            var thing = _context.Users.Find(-1);

            if (thing == null)
                return NotFound();

            else
                return thing;
        }

        [HttpGet("server-error")]
        public ActionResult<string> GetServerError()
        {
            var thing = _context.Users.Find(-1);

            var thingToReturn = thing.ToString();

            return thingToReturn;
        }

        [HttpGet("bad-request")]
        public ActionResult<string> GetBadRequest()
        {
            return BadRequest("This was not a good request");
        }
    }
}
```

The angular component to test the exceptions:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-errors',
  templateUrl: './test-errors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-errors.component.css']
})
export class TestErrorsComponent implements OnInit {
  baseUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get404Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'buggy/not-found').subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response)


    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })  

  }

  get400ValidationError() {
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'buggy/register', {}).subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response)


    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }


  get400Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'buggy/bad-request').subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response)


    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })

  }

  get500Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'buggy/server-error').subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response)


    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })

  }

  get401Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'buggy/auth').subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response)


    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })

  }
}
```

I would very much appreciate some assistance on why am i getting the status text as ok. I double and triple checked everything and its still the same. Thank you in advnace

Comment: Could you check the raw HTTP response in the F12 tools? Is there a status text being sent? The first line for my blog for example is "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".

Comment: I just checked, same result. statusText:"ok"

Comment: The status text is neither prescribed by the standard ("The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations - they can be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol") nor important, so you probably don't need to test it.

Comment: Please check the exception handler, perhaps you configured the application to use the custom exception handler, and in the exception handler you have changed the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the course's QA in Udemy. It has to do with http/2 and default values in angular client itself. In short in http/2 requests the statusText is removed from the response and angular fills in the missing info with default data ( being statusText=Ok ). It's also a problem cited elsewhere

[Course link](https://www.udemy.com/course/build-an-app-with-aspnet-core-and-angular-from-scratch/learn/lecture/22400824#questions/14077526)
[main reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23334)