# statusText and statusCode in response requests not related

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-5.0

am trying to cerate components for testing errors in angular and define this method in angular:

```
  get400Error() {
     this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'buggy/bad-request').subscribe(Response => {
       console.log(Response)
     }, error => {
       console.log(error);
     })
 }
```

and this method in asp.net:

```
[HttpGet("bad-request")]
public ActionResult<string> GetBadRequest()
{
    return BadRequest("This was not a good request");
}
```

but when call this method
message in console chrome is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTd6n.png)

Comment: statusText must be equal to "bad request"

Comment: I'm find answers from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66496153/13138343